# Mobile app (iOS) security dump memory dump (Frida)

Tags: ios, unit-testing, security, xamarin

We have an issue with releasing our mobile app as user data have been found with the iOS memory, which is odd as we have used secure data storage though out the mobile app. Before we send the mobile app for a re-test we would like to understand in-house to verify our changes have fixed the issue.

Data has been found in the following locations:

```
 /Data/Library/Preferences/XXX.plist
 /Data/Library/Cachces/XXX/Cache.db-wal
 /Data/Library/Cachces/XXX
```

After a lot of research we are still unclear how we can download the iOS memory, we are not sure if it's a major test development tool investigate or we can do it with Frida? Our development platform is Xamarin and I would think it would be possible to view the memory using a debugger via the simulator?

Just looking for advise if this is something very simple using a simple commercial
software/mobile app etc Or highly complex with specialist development tool.